# C++ decltype fails to deduce type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, decltype

Is decltype really buggy in Visual Studio 2012 or is it actually supposed to be this hard to use?

Example:

```
namespace ptl
{

    struct Test
    {
        Test(float ){}
    };

    template<class T, class A0>
    static T* static_constructor(void* p, A0 a0){return new(p) T(a0);}

    template<class T>
    T*  MakeVS2012Happy(T*);
}

inline auto ExampleFxn() -> decltype(ptl::MakeVS2012Happy(&ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>)) 
{
   return &ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>;
}
inline auto ExampleFxn2() -> decltype(&ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>)
{
   return &ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>;
}
```

ExampleFxn compiles because I've wrapped the code in the decltype with that pointless function.

ExampleFxn2 does not, VS2012 spits out the extremely helpful error message:

error C3555: incorrect argument to 'decltype'

Anyone know what causes this? I seem to constantly have to fight against decltype to get it to work as expected...

Thanks

Comment: This issue is still present as of VC++ 2013 Update 4.

Comment: That workaround works pretty well actually! If you remove the `*`s from `MakeVS2012Happy`, it also works for nonstatic member functions.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in VC++ 2015 RC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `&ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>` can be deduced by `decltype()`. This looks like a bug in MSVC++. Both clang and gcc agree that the code is fine (assuming `#include <new>` is added).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Dietmar:  This is a bug in the compiler.  The issue appears to be that `decltype` cannot be applied to an expression that takes the address of a function template specialization.  That is, the following is a minimal repro for this issue:

```
template <typename>
void f();

typedef decltype(&f<void>) t;
```

As a workaround, consider applying `decltype` to the function template specialization directly, then adding `*` to form the required pointer type:

```
inline auto ExampleFxn2()
    -> decltype(ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>)*
{
   return &ptl::static_constructor<ptl::Test, float>;
}
```

Please consider opening a bug for this on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and posting a link as a comment here for future readers (or, if you would prefer not to, let me know and I would be happy to open a bug for this issue).

Comment: I made a connect bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775434/decltype-is-buggy-in-vs-2012

Comment: Your work around works for your minimal repro case, and in a test I made using the above code. But in my real code making this change is not fixing it.

Comment: in your example if "f" is overloaded it will not work.  God damnit decltype is buggy as hell in VS2012:(