# difference between typeids of template and non-template member function pointers

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to figure out the root cause of a type conversion issue with pointers to member functions in C++ (VS2012).

I've narrowed it down to the difference in the `typeid` of a pointer to a template member function and a non-template member function. Consider the code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
    public:    
        template<int k>
        void func1() {}

        void func2() {}
};

typedef void (foo::*foofunc)();

int main()
{
    //this gives "int"
    std::cout<<typeid(&foo::func1<3>).name()<<std::endl;

    //this gives "void (__thiscall *)(void)"
    std::cout<<typeid(&foo::func2).name()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`func2` has the expected value. Why does a pointer to `func1` have type `int` when both are member functions of the same class?

**NOTE**: This happens only on Windows.

Comment: On GCC 4.8, they both print `M3fooFvvE`

Comment: @PaoloM: Yeah. I'm not sure why the name is obscure but at least they both seem to have the same type with GCC.

Comment: What do you mean by obscure? By the way, this is from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid): There is no guarantee that the same std::type_info instance will be referred to by all evaluations of the typeid expression on the same type, although std::type_info::hash_code of those type_info objects would be identical, as would be their std::type_index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This clearly is a compiler bug in VS 2012. It looks closely related to [#775434 "decltype is buggy in VS 2012"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775434/decltype-is-buggy-in-vs-2012) which links to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085274/c-decltype-fails-to-deduce-type). If this is indeed the bug, then you besides upgrading to VS 2015, you could try a workaround similar to this ([src](https://github.com/Oberon00/apollo/blob/5940d07f277951a7faad5c53eb9e5f44f12c7de7/include/apollo/detail/meta_util.hpp#L41)):

```
template <typename T> T msvc_decltype_helper(T); // Never implemented.
#define FN_DECLTYPE(...) decltype(::msvc_decltype_helper(__VA_ARGS__))
```

I.e. try what `typeid(msvc_decltype_helper(&foo::func1<3>)).name()` outputs.